# I added a button and set it onClick, but an error message appears. Please reply

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing an error on React, and I have to solve them.

error meesage:
Warning:Expected 'onClick' listener to be a function, instead got a value of 'string' type.

Book.js is a component of App.js. The book component receives the API from json of 'App.js' and is used as the value of the book function. How do I use onClick?

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
state={
  item=[]
}
getBook =async () =>{
const {
 data: {item}
} = await axios.get("book.json")
 this.setState({item})
}
componentDidMount(){
this.getBook();
}
render(){
 const {item}=this.state;
 return(
 <div>
  {item.map(Book=>(
   <Book
      buy={book.link}
   />
  </div>
 }
export default App;
```

Book.js

```
function Book({buy}){
return(
        <button onClick={buy}>Buy</button>
      )

Book.protoTypes={
    buy:ProtoTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Book;
```

Comment: buy is a string, it should be function.

Comment: Could you create a minimal code which reproduces the error.Please add code instead of image

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Please put an error to the topic as text next time, and explain your scenario for helping others more understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are passing a string value, when you should actually be passing a method to the `onClick` event.

This is how you should fix it:

```
const buy = () => {
 // do the rest here
}

return <button onClick={() => this.buy()}> some text </button>
```